# Make Btrfs use all CPUs for compression

Tags: btrfs, compression

I have been playing around with Btrfs and compression, but I have been unable to make Btrfs use all my CPU cores for compressing.

The kernel compression processes max out at 8 cores (all running >90%) of the 64 available - no matter if I am writing to 1, 10, or 64 files in parallel.

```
top - 23:34:36 up  1:30,  4 users,  load average: 12.96, 13.03, 12.12
Tasks: 891 total,  20 running, 871 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us, 19.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 80.2 id,  0.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
GiB Mem :    503.9 total,      1.2 free,     16.6 used,    486.1 buff/cache
GiB Swap:    296.5 total,    263.5 free,     33.0 used.    465.3 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                
 177631 root      20   0       0      0      0 R  97.2   0.0  19:44.32 kworker/u132:13+btrfs-delalloc                         
 178092 root      20   0       0      0      0 R  97.2   0.0   6:15.42 kworker/u132:17+btrfs-delalloc                         
 178059 root      20   0       0      0      0 R  96.1   0.0  13:33.27 kworker/u132:6+btrfs-delalloc                          
 178088 root      20   0       0      0      0 R  95.9   0.0   6:32.18 kworker/u132:11+btrfs-delalloc                         
 177182 root      20   0       0      0      0 R  95.6   0.0  21:03.04 kworker/u132:1+btrfs-delalloc                          
 178089 root      20   0       0      0      0 R  95.6   0.0   5:06.10 kworker/u132:14+btrfs-delalloc                         
 177606 root      20   0       0      0      0 R  95.0   0.0  18:35.88 kworker/u132:7+btrfs-delalloc                          
 178050 root      20   0       0      0      0 R  89.8   0.0   7:56.04 kworker/u132:2+btrfs-delalloc                          
 177938 tange     20   0    7820   2948   2652 R  84.6   0.0  27:54.08 cp                                                     
    543 root      20   0       0      0      0 R  71.9   0.0   5:40.39 kswapd4                                                
 177951 root      20   0       0      0      0 I  24.8   0.0   0:30.06 kworker/u135:11-btrfs-endio                            
 178053 root      20   0       0      0      0 I  23.4   0.0   0:40.41 kworker/u135:16-btrfs-endio
```

How can I tell Btrfs that it is OK to use all 64 cores - the remaining 56 cores are sitting idle anyway?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `thread_pool` option while mounting the filesystem?

Comment: @rickhg12hs Yes. I can make it increase the CPU usage, but I/O is not faster. So basically I can choose to waste CPU time.

Comment: If you are IO bound, then yeah, more CPU allocation won't help.

Comment: @rickhg12hs This is done in a RAM disk, so we are not waiting for IO to SSD/HD.

Comment: Ah, I over-interpreted your previous statement "I/O is not faster".  If your CPU is working harder, but the I/O isn't increasing, I'd also like to know what the bottleneck is.  However, `thread_pool` does seem to address your original question, yes?

Comment: @rickhg12hs No. The ideas was to get more CPUs do the compression, not just be active doing nothing. The cores are firing on all cylinders but they do not compress faster. https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs(5) says: "higher numbers could lead to a performance hit due to increased locking contention, process scheduling, cache-line bouncing or costly data transfers between local CPU memories." which might be what I am seeing.

Comment: All true.  I hope you can find a way to "Make Btrfs use all CPUs for compression".

Comment: Have you tried different compression algorithms and especially using `compress-force` to bypass btrfs's own compressability check?